# C# Web Application Pop Up Confimation Dialog Box

Tags: c#, asp.net, dialog

I am trying to do when textBox autoPostBack. a pop up confirmation dialog box will appear. If user choose Okay, then perform something. If user choose Cancel, then get back the previous text in textBox. So far, I've found a solution for a pop up message in C# web application:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "UserDialogScript", "alert(\"Insufficient storage\");", true);
```

However, this message box do not have button on it. I looking forwards for solutions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Below:

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(GetType(), "UserDialogScript", "return confirm(\"Insufficient storage\");document.getElementById(id).value='test';", true);
```

Check the value of this id control, if it is set then true otherwise false.

Comment: How I know if the user pressed Okay or Cancel?

Comment: What does this line do? document.getElementById(id).value='test';

Comment: This will set the value in any control. u can check on the internet abt it.

Answer (score 0):

```
Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "UserDialogScript", "UserDialogScript();", true);    


add javascript function//
function UserDialogScript()
        {
            if (confirm("Are you sure?"))
            {  return true;
            }else{return false;}
        }
```

This should help u.

Comment: How can I call the function? bool userChoice = UserDialogScript() ?

Comment: Confirm is a jvascript function that adds a confirm popup with 'Ok' and 'Cancel' button.
this function returns 'true' if OK is clicked and 'false' if Cancel is clicked.
@Gwen, do this answer you question.?